# upload an app twice in app server and meet errors

Tags: wso2, datasource, jndi, appserver

I am testing the JNDI datasource with sample downloaded from url [1]. I upload the app as a tenant, and register the datasource in the context.xml of the app.
upload the app to AS, with no version number, click go to URl and find the app is working, and achieve the data from database; delete the app from the console, upload the app to AS, with version number 0.1.2

then the back-end console show some errors:

[2013-12-17 17:18:13,816] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat} -  Webapp StandardContext[/carbonDSwebApp/0.1.2] failed to deploy
[2013-12-17 17:18:13,817] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TomcatGenericWebappsDeployer} -  Error while deploying webapp: StandardContext[carbonDSwebApp#0.1.2.war].File[F:\OPENSO~1\WSO2\WSO2AS~1.0\bin..\repository\deployment\server\webapps\carbonDSwebApp#0.1.2.war]
org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.CarbonTomcatException: Webapp failed to deploy
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: no !/ in spec

then no matter how many times of deletion and upload, this app is no longer able to be ploaded.

[1] http://dinushasblog.blogspot.com/2011/12/how-to-access-carbon-data-source-from.html

Comment: unless I restart AS. I also get a jenkins.war pack, and upload->delete->upload again, and AS throw some exception too.

Comment: I think this is a bug, and could someone look in to this issue?